# How to put Facebook Dialog box within a custom modal/html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a Facebook modal dialog box that I would like to place within a custom modal dialog box (as an html element).  This is what I have so far:

For Facebook Dialog:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.init({ appId: '***************', cookie: true, xfbml: true, oauth: true });

    // *** here is my code ***
    if (typeof facebookInit == 'function') {
        facebookInit();
    }
};

(function(d){
    var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
}(document));

function facebookInit() {
   FB.ui({
    url : 'http://www.google.com',
    method: 'feed',
    name: 'The name',
    link: 'crowd.com',
    caption: 'An example caption',
}, function (response) {
    if (response && response.post_id) {
        alert('Post was published.');
    } else {
        alert('Post was not published.');
    }
}); 
}
});
```

For the modal:

```
<div id="myModal1new" class="modal1 hide welcome-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
</div>

<div class="modal-header"></div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div id="fb-root"></div>
            </div>
```

Is there anyway I can combine these two (place the FB dialog within the custom modal)?  Maybe with an iframe of sorts?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: can we have a playground?

Answer (score 3):

Bad news you can't do that, all the urls facebooks has for sharing like `sharer.php` and the feed dialog by url, like this one:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?
  app_id=145634995501895
  &display=page&caption=An%20example%20caption 
  &link=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fdialogs%2F
  &redirect_uri=https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer
```

won't render inside an iframe, since facebook blocks all it's content to be rendered inside one. Here's the error that is thrown when you try to create an iframe with facebook content:

```
Refused to display 'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.
```

Since you can't use iframes and the feed dialog opens up a new window every time, the only way you can accomplish something similar is creating your own "share dialog", but remember for this to work, you will have to ask users permissions to post on their behalf.

Comment: How would I go about creating my own share dialog?

Comment: What do you need to know? Does these docs answers your question? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/web/share and this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#publishing